# Script is skipping function

Tags: python, linux, function

I have no idea whats going on with this code, for some reason it seems to just skip the function entirely.

```
    try:
        readHandle = open(fileName, 'r')
    except IOError, ioe:
        print "Cannot open file: ", fileName,"\n"
        print "%s" %ioe
        raise

    lines = readHandle.readlines()

    lineNum = 1



    #read file line by line
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith(':'):
            #remove : from line
            bits0 = line.partition(':')
            #remove \n newlines
            bits1 = bits0[2].partition('\n')
            #split in to an array using , as delimiter
            bits2 = bits1[0].split(',')

            DrvrNum = bits2[0]
            DrvrNam = bits2[1]

            # Debug
            if DBUG == 1:
                print "DrvrNum and DrvrNam variable values"
                print DrvrNum, DrvrNam

            crcDrvr(DrvrNum, DrvrNam)

        elif line.startswith('#'):

            #Comment line
            pass
        elif line.startswith('Ss'):
            #Crc line
            pass
        elif line.startswith('Zz'):
            #end of file
            pass

        else:
            print '\nError: line', lineNum , 'is an illegal entry'
            print '\nPlease Check'
            sys,exit(0)


        lineNum = lineNum + 1
```

This is the function that is being skipped:

```
def crcDrvr(number,name):

        convNum = int(number,16)            
        convNam = ''

        for char in name:

            hexChar = char.encode("hex") 
            print hexChar
```

can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong to cause my code to skip?

Sample data:

```
#DrvrDB
#
#    
#
Ss1234
:744,Bob Hope
:747,Testy Tester
:777,Extra Guy
:0,dummy
Zz
#Driver#,DriverName
#end of file padding 1
```

Comment: is the code below 'if line.startswith(':') definitely being executed?

Comment: Can you add a sample of the file?

Comment: @barny Yes, it definitely is because I still get the print out from the DBUG if statement

Comment: @Szymon I have added some sample data as requested

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this code. Does it print `print "DrvrNum and DrvrNam variable values"`?

Comment: @Szymon yes it does but after that it completely skips `crcDrvr(DrvrNum, DrvrNam)`

Comment: How do you know it's skipped?

Comment: @Szymon I figured it out, some genius create the function `crcDrvr` twice with only a variable declaration so it must have been hitting that one

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, some genius create the function `crcDrvr` twice with only a variable declaration so it must have been hitting that one
                    – Jim